# starting Matlab script from command line doesn't find DLL on the path

Tags: dll, command-line, matlab

I have a Matlab script that requires a function in a DLL, and calls `addpath` to put it's location on the path. This works fine, but when I try to invoke the same script on the command line with `matlab -r "scriptname"` it errors out saying that method is undefined. Is there something different happening when I'm starting from the command line vs loading up the GUI normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out both 64-bit and 32-bit versions of matlab were installed, and the first one in the path was the 64-bit, whereas I needed the 32-bit for things to work.